# ServiceStack.OrmLite SQL Server doesn't load third level of references?

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I tried to load a table with 3 levels of references using `ServiceStack.OrmLite SQL Server`, it loaded only until the second level:

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite

```
MasterAccounts.Contacts.ContactType
```

I tried using the command: `LoadSelect<MasterAccounts>(x => x)`

It loaded the `Contacts` reference, but didn't load the `ContactType`.

Below is possible to see that I put the data annotations correctly:

```
[References(typeof(MasterAccountContactType))]
public int MasterAccountContactTypeId { get; set; }
[Reference]
public MasterAccountContactType MasterAccountContactType { get; set; }
```

So, is there any limitations to load third level references?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As specified in [documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/README.md#querying-pocos-with-references)

> Loads related data only 1-reference-level deep